# Error with spark-csv on Amazon EMR Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-csv

I am attempting to run an EMR cluster with a simple Spark step execution and I am encountering an error that I can not resolve.  The program works when I run it locally in Eclipse, but not when I run it on an EMR cluster.  The program is simply trying to convert a CSV file on S3 into Parquet format.

When I run in EMR, I get the following error:

> *Caused by: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: Length of parsed input (1000001) exceeds the maximum number of characters defined in your parser settings (1000000).* 
>   *Identified line separator characters in the parsed content. This may be the cause of the error. The line separator in your parser settings is set to '\n'. Parsed content:*

I do not have any fields over the 1000000 limit.  I have tried reading from s3, s3n, and s3a locations.

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    object TestEMR {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Convert to Parquet").getOrCreate()
        val schema = StructType(
            Array(
              StructField("field1", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field2", IntegerType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field3", IntegerType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field4", TimestampType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field5", TimestampType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field6", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field7", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field8", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field9", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field10", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field11", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field12", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field13", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field14", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field15", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field16", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field17", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field18", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field19", StringType ,nullable = true),
              StructField("field20", StringType ,nullable = true)
            )
          )

        val df = spark.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .schema(schema)
            .option("nullValue","")
            .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true")
            .load("s3://mybucket/input/myfile.csv")
       df.write.mode("append").parquet("s3://mybucket/output/myfile")
       spark.stop
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it's not finding the line ending, so reads in continually until it hits that limit of 10K chars on a single line.

As they say: check that file's newline

Comment: The file is fine.  The load operation just isn't splitting the file on newline.  I was able to convert the code to sc.texfile(myfile) and it read the file fine.

Comment: interesting. FWIW Spark 2 has a built in CSV parser, which means you get to file JIRAs against the spark team. The s3a integration tests I run do work with a .csv.gz file on s3 with that module

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still open in [spark-csv jira](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/295). They have provided workaround like using the open csv parser if you don't have data issue or reading as RDD and then creating a dataframe.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file.csv")
// Here, filtering or transformation
//val filteredRDD = rdd.filter..
//val transformedRDD = rdd.map..

val df = new CsvParser().csvRdd(sqlContext, transformedRDD)
```